# What is wrong with my geopy great circle distance computation?

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geopy, great-circle

I want to compute the distance (in km) using geopy library between two points defined by their respective (lat, lon) coordinates.

My code

```
from geopy.distance import great_circle

# lat, lon
p1 = (45.8864, -7.2305)
p2 = (46.2045, -7.2305)

# distance in km
great_circle(p1, p2).km
>>> 35.371156132664765
```

To check above results, I used the tool available here: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html but the two outputs do not match.

[image]

The output of my code is `35.371156132664765` though the above tool returns a distance of 15.41 km.
How come the results are different ?

Comment: You're using the web tool incorrectly. You have entered values as degrees, minutes, seconds not decimal degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation for the points `p1` and `p2` is wrong, you need to convert the minutes and seconds into degree correctly. Otherwise the code works prefectly.